# Material Calendar View in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to show a CalendarView control in which I can have custom background for each dates and use custom selectors. I could find examples of Material DatePicker, but did not find any CalendarView control which I can customize. Can we customize [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) control in Android SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we cannot customize CalendarView widget. We will need to use an external library for that. I could not find a good one in Xamarin.Android where we can have custom drawables as a background. So I bound a [Java Library](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) for that.

You can download the binding project from GitHub using this [link](https://github.com/sreerajPR/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView)

After you add a reference to the binding project you can easily integrate the widget as below:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/primary"
    app:mcv_arrowColor="@color/primary" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Sreeraj :) but unfortunately I cannot use an external library as of now,will try some other work around then.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/msioen/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView Perhaps it'll be useful for somebody