# Android (Xamarin) binding project for Android Studio library

Tags: android, xamarin, calendar

I'm trying to use an external library from android into my Xamarin.Android application, but am facing quite a few issues.

The external library I require is a Calendar library. After looking at Xamarin Component's limited collection of Calendar library, I was unable to find one that suits the needs of my application. I then read up on using Android Studio's external libraries, using [this Xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) and [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWkuk1Mgf8g).

However, of the two libraries I've tried -

- [Material Calendar View](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)
- [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

both were not able to build.

Here is the error list when I try to build Material Calendar View:

```
The type or namespace name 'CalendarPagerView' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
'WeekView.ThresholdClass': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.ThresholdType': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.Rows': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.BuildDayViews(ICollection<DayView>, Calendar)': no suitable method found to override
The type or namespace name 'DayView' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
'WeekView.IsDayEnabled(CalendarDay)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.OnClick(View)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.OnInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetDateTextAppearance(int)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetDayFormatter(IDayFormatter)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetMaximumDate(CalendarDay)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetMinimumDate(CalendarDay)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetSelectedDates(ICollection)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetSelectionColor(int)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetSelectionEnabled(bool)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetShowOtherDates(int)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetWeekDayFormatter(IWeekDayFormatter)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.SetWeekDayTextAppearance(int)': no suitable method found to override
'WeekView.ShouldDelayChildPressedState()': no suitable method found to override
'IExperimentalInvoker.Equals(Object)' hides inherited member 'Object.Equals(Object)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
'IExperimentalInvoker.GetHashCode()' hides inherited member 'Object.GetHashCode()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
'IExperimentalInvoker.ToString()' hides inherited member 'Object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
The member 'WeekView.java_class_handle' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
The member 'WeekView.class_ref' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.
top ancestor WeekPagerAdapter not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.WeekPagerAdapter.Weekly.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.IShowOtherDates.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.SavedState.1.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.4.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.ISelectionMode.
top ancestor MonthPagerAdapter not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MonthPagerAdapter.Monthly.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.LayoutParams.
Unknown parameter type com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView in method OnRangeSelected in managed type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.IOnRangeSelectedListener.
Invalid return type com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.CalendarPagerView.LayoutParams in method GenerateLayoutParams in managed type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.WeekView.
Invalidating Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.IOnRangeSelectedListener and all nested types because some of its methods were invalid.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.SavedState.
Unknown parameter type com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView in method OnDateSelected in managed type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.IOnDateSelectedListener.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.1.
For StateBuilder, could not find enclosing type 'MaterialCalendarView'.
Unknown parameter type com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView in method OnMonthChanged in managed type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.IOnMonthChangedListener.
Invalidating Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.IOnDateSelectedListener and all nested types because some of its methods were invalid.
Unknown parameter type com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView in method CalendarPagerView in managed type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.CalendarPagerView.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.State.
Invalidating Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.IOnMonthChangedListener and all nested types because some of its methods were invalid.
top ancestor MaterialCalendarView not found for nested type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.StateBuilder.
Unknown parameter type com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView in method WeekView in managed type Com.Prolificinteractive.Materialcalendarview.WeekView.
ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
missing class error was raised while reflecting com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView : android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener
Couldn't load class com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MonthPagerAdapter : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter
Couldn't load class com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/CalendarPager : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager
Couldn't load class com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MaterialCalendarView$3 : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$PageTransformer
Couldn't load class com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/CalendarPagerAdapter : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter
Couldn't load class com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MaterialCalendarView$2 : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener
Couldn't load class android/support/v4/view/BetterViewPager : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager
Couldn't load class com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/WeekPagerAdapter : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter
```

Caldroid also produces a similar error list.

I have tried directly using existing Xamarin libraries for the library, such as the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735412/material-calendar-view-in-xamarin-android) but also had similar build problems, which led me to believe I was probably doing something obviously wrong, but I can't figure it out.

As I'm rather new to Android development, a step-by-step guide to bind this exact library would help me out a lot.

#### ---Update---

After building the library and adding it as a reference in my project, viewing the library in the object browser shows that it is empty.

[image: Object browser]

Missing members and error:

[image: Object browser 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project solution, you could choose `Add Existing Project`, add a `MaterialCalendarLibrary` from [Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView](https://github.com/sreerajPR/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView)  project.

Then you could follow this [Xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/#Using_the_Bindings_Library), to use the `material-calendarview`. All works fine and if I found a better solution I will come back and update this answer.

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVEU3.png).

**EDIT :**

Its [object browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdkhr.png).

Comment: I have followed the steps but the MaterialCalendarLibrary in the object browser is empty

Comment: @Ryalis, you mean this [project](https://github.com/sreerajPR/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView) is empty?

Comment: @Ryalis, when you download the `.zip` file and add a `MaterialCalendarLibrary` from it has any problem?

Comment: I have updated the post with a screenshot. There were no problems when building the library, but building the whole solution with the library added as a reference gives this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/view/BetterViewPager;`

Comment: Looks like mine is incomplete. There are many missing members of `MaterialCalendarLibrary`. Perhaps it has something to do with the error in my previous comment? How do I resolve that error?

Comment: @Ryalis, `MaterialCalendarLibrary` library add a reference on `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`, and your project did same thing, make sure their version is same.

Comment: @Ryalis, open your project `Manage Nuget packages`  and update you `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` package to the latest.

Comment: Turns out I already have `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7` which conflicts with v4. Uninstalling v4 solved the issue. The calendar library is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149615/discussion-between-ryalis-and-york-shen).

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I wonder do we need to export jar from this github project or as aar?

Comment: @IshworKhanal, you could directly use the [MaterialCalendarLibrary](https://github.com/sreerajPR/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView/tree/master/MaterialCalendarLibrary) library or export the jar file to create your own [Java Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/).

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT but there is old version of aar file  how can I get the latest version of aar file? Thank you.

Comment: @IshworKhanal, you could use google to find the latest `.aar` file and the refer to [this](https://github.com/sreerajPR/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView/tree/master/MaterialCalendarLibrary/Transforms) to create your own `MaterialCalendarLibrary`. If there is any problem when you binding the java library you could refer to this [Troubleshooting Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/).

Comment: I tried your project on my project but was unable to set weekview mode as it says out of index array error.

Comment: @IshworKhanal, you could open a new question and post more complete message for a better solution.